# Python Tkinter application fit on screen

Tags: python, tkinter, screen

I have designed an application using the Tkinter module from Python, on my 17"
screen.

Is there a way to make this app fit on lower resolution screens? I have tried to run it on a 14" screen, and the app doesn`t fit well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the screen resolution then input them in your `root.geometry`, this way:

```
from Tkinker import *

root = Tk()

width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (width,height))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you use this technique the OS doesn't think it's full screen

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this one line:

root.state('zoomed') #works on all operating systems

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
```

This will fit the window perfectly to the display. (Note: This is not full screen function. Full screen means the window will also cover the taskbar, but in this code window fits all over the screen except the taskbar)